# How to show multiple size classes in xcode 6

Tags: xcode6

The link below shows that it's possible to display various versions of an IOS app side by side (left hand side the normal view, right hand side shows multiple views for different devices).

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH6-SW1

I can only show the regular "size classes" view (on the left of the example). Has anyone figured out how to show iphone/ipad etc in one pane and the regular design view in the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- select storyboard
- open assistent editor
- open dropdown menu in the menu bar of the assistant editor screen (where it says 'manual' or 'automatic')
- select Preview. 
  With the +-button you can add the devices and orientations you like to preview